# where the Password and Username is stored in Apache Ignite?

Tags: java, caching, server, ignite

> I am able to connect the java thin client to server by the following code,

```
ClientConfiguration cfg = new ClientConfiguration()
        .setAddresses("127.0.0.1:10800")
        .setUserName("JP")
        .setUserPassword("Jol");
```

> Now my question is where the username and password is stored(in which table)? how can i view that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users and passwords are not stored in a table, Ignite uses internal data structure for that.

There is no way to retrieve existing users. You can alter known users with DDL: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/advanced-security